# Scalar equation is uniformly asymptotically stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Would you please help me to verify that if constant $a$ is positive, then the zero solution of the scalar equation 
$$
x'=-ax,
$$ 
is uniformly asymptotically stable.

Comment: Did you write your equation properly or did you mean $x' = -a x$?

Comment: WOuld you please help me to verify that if constant a>0 then the zero solution of the scalar equation x′=−ax is uniformly asymptotically stable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of *uniformly asymptotically stability* knowing that the solution of your equation is
$$
x(t)=x_0\mathrm{e}^{-at}.
$$

Comment: I could not find :( So sorry would you please explain step by step